# Firestore query on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection

```
created_at: 28 January 2023 at 14:41:04 UTC+5
id: "e44a154f-b0cb-4ef6-bc27-af37f178b46c"
message: "1 Orders has been uploaded successfully"
read: true
writer: "16315bd844e95c5926a92bda9"
```

I want to write a query for getting all the records form the notifications collections which are **orderBy** **created_at** and where **writer === "16315bd844e95c5926a92bda9"**

I have tried this query

```
const ref = collection(db, "notifications")
query(
  ref, 
  where("writer", "==", '16315bd844e95c5926a92bda9'), 
  orderBy('created_at', 'desc'), 
  limit(5)
)
```

but it does not showing any data.

But when i delete the **orderBy** part its filtering the collection

Comment: The query in your question needs a composite index, which you need to add manually. If you (catch errors and) check the log output, you'll find an error message about a missing index, which included a link to the Firebase console where you can create the index with a single click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query in your question needs a composite index, which (unlike single-field indexes) you need to add yourself.

If you (catch errors and) check the log output, you'll find an error message about a missing index, which included a link to the Firebase console where you can create the index with a single click.

Comment: I happened to create index at firebase where I set the created_at desc, but when i am querying by asc its giving me error. Is there a way to query by both order i.e. ace and desc?